# Filter nested json based on certain values using python

Tags: python, json, csv, filter

Let's say I have a json structure like below

```
{
    "timeStamp": 1630918356182,
    "type": "company", # possible values: food, company
    "pref": {
        "food": {
            "value": "veg"
        },
        "company": [
            "A",
            "B"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want it to be converted as below (flattened json post filtering). The filtering is done on nested 'pref' object based on the value from 'type'.

```
1630918356182 company A
1630918356182 company B
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The function from the below code will filter out the value as desire

```
def filter_data(data: dict):
    if data and 'type' in data:
        type =  data['type']
        
        time_stamp = data.get("timeStamp", "")

        if  'pref' in data:
            for value in data['pref'].get(type, []):
                yield time_stamp, type, value



if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = {
        "timeStamp": 1630918356182,
        "type": "company", # possible values: food, company
        "pref": {
            "food": {
                "value": "veg"
            },
            "company": [
                "A",
                "B"
            ]
        }
    }

    result = filter_data(data)
    for time_stamp, type, value in result:
        print(time_stamp, type, value)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.